# Limit Point of a Set

Tags: real-analysis, definition, intuition

Definition. A point $x$ is a *limit point* of a set A if every $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ intersects the set A in some point other than $x$.

I understand the definition in that $x$ is our limit point for the set A. What I don't understand is where it says "intersects" the set A in some point other than $x$. Can some one explain what is meant by "intersect"?

Comment: Let the $e$-neighborhood be $X$, then $X\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and $x\not\in X\cap A$.

Comment: Also, you could say that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$ different from $x$ itself.

Comment: I like the definition used in the notes of Terence Tao: 

Adherent point: We say that $c$ is an adherent point of $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ iff given a $\varepsilon>0$ there is $x\in A$ such that $|x-c|< \varepsilon$.

Limit point: We say that $c$ is a limit point of $A \subset \mathbb{R}$  if is an adherent point of $A\setminus\{c\}$, i.e., there is a $x\in A\setminus\{c\}$ so that $|x-c|< \varepsilon$

Answer (score 0):

For example in $\Bbb R$ the subset $\Bbb N$  has'nt any  limit point:

If  $n \in \Bbb N$  then for example $]n-1/2,n+1/2[$ intersects $\Bbb N$ only in $\{n\}$.

$A=\left\{0,1,\frac 12, \frac 13, ....\right\}$  has a unique limite point : that is $0$.

because for all $\varepsilon > 0$, we have :  $(]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[)\cap A =\{\frac 1p,p>\frac 1{\varepsilon}\} $  but  for  $n \in \Bbb N, n \neq 0$  and $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2n(n+1)}$  we  have  $A \cap (]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[)=\{\frac 1n \}$